# Simple Rspec test for positive number just won't pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and trying to write my first app. I have a table with columns order_size:integer and price:decimal(8,5). The price column holds currency prices so it needs to be really precise, in case you're wondering. I'm trying to write tests to make sure the price and order_size are a positive numbers, but no matter what I do they won't pass.

Here are the Rspec tests

```
it "should require a positive order size" do
  @attr[:order_size] = -23
  @user.orders.create!(@attr).should_not be_valid
end

it "should require a positive price" do
  @attr[:price] = -1.2908
  @user.orders.create!(@attr).should_not be_valid
end
```

Here are the Order class validations

```
  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates_numericality_of :order_size, :greater_than => 0,
                            :only_integer => true
  validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than => 0
```

Here's the test results

```
Failures:

  1) Order validations should require a positive order size
     Failure/Error: @user.orders.create!(@attr).should_not be_valid
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Order size must be greater than 0
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Order validations should require a positive price
     Failure/Error: @user.orders.create!(@attr).should_not be_valid
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Price must be greater than 0
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:44:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What exactly is going on here? I even tried running the test asserting they should be_valid, but they still fail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like the creation of the records is failing due to your validations, and thus never getting to your assertion!  As apneadiving points out, you want to do:

```
order = Order.new(:order_size => -23)
order.should_not be_valid
```

Comment: Indeed, i would also test it like this: purely on `Order`. The validation of an order does not depend on the fact whether or not it is part of a `@user`.

Answer (score 0):

why do you call `create!` just call `new`

Or change your test to expect the creation to fail.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. But both methods do essentially the same thing, except for that 'create' actually saves it. Is that why it wasn't working? It was failing on a lower level and not getting a change to even run the test?

Comment: Yep, ActiveRecord did fail and so your test. I think you could test ActiveRecord failure using should raise_error but it's much better to check if object is valid using new.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to write this test. You are using the `create!` method, which will raise an exception when it fails. So in that case you would write your test as follows:

```
it "should require a positive order size" do
  @attr[:order_size] = -23
  expect { @user.orders.create!(@attr)}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new)
end
```

But, actually, the fact that the `create!` does raise an exception when an `order` is not valid, is rails-specific, so i would actually test it as proposed by @mharper.